# How can I see which application is using Bin, so that it cannot be emptied?

Tags: macos, mojave, catalina

How can I see which application is using the Bin, so that it cannot be emptied?

I've so many tasks and projects open, so I'd rather not restart the macOS Catalina.

I have tried looking in `Activity Monitor`, but couldn't figure it out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to answers on the Ask Different question [Cannot empty trash](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/40212/122152), you can use either

```
ps -eal | grep $(fuser ~/.Trash)
```

or

```
lsof | grep Trash
```

in the Terminal to find out which process is using the Trash.

Comment: The `ps -eal | grep $(fuser ~/.Trash)` doesn't work anymore. `fuser` suffix each with PID with a "c", and `grep` tries to open them as files.